# multi data from different schema, angular display

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a really long json that each comes from different schema.
I did push in order to get them all in one json - that works.
know I want to use a controller for all of them and display it to the screen.

my index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="showFrozen">
 <head>
 <title>frozen</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="showFrozenCtrl">
 <tbody>
 <div ng-repeat="themes in showFrozenController.themes" ng-show="$first">
  <h2>{{themes.theme}}</h2>
 <span>for age: </span>
 <p>{{themes.age}}</p>
 <span>description: </span>
 <p>{{themes.description}}</p>
  <p>{{themes.description_more}}</p>
 <img ng-src="{{themes.image}}" width="170" height="170">
 </div>

 </table>
    <script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/showFrozenController.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

my controller

```
var showFrozen = angular.module('showFrozen',[]);
showFrozen.filter("allItems", function() {
    return function(frozen) {
        var resultArr = [];
        angular.forEach(frozen,function(item) {
                resultArr.push(item);
        });
        return resultArr;
    };
});
var model = {};

showFrozen.run(function($http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/frozen").success(function(data){
       console.log(data);
        model.frozen = data;
    });
});
showFrozen.controller('showFrozenCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.showFrozenController = model;
});
```

so I don't get any output - but I see the json in the console, I'm attaching an image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your controller model is undefined.
Move the HTTP call to your controller and in the success assign the scope.showFrozenController to data

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't understand how is it undefined if I see the json in the console...

Comment: And it's not good practice to do HTTP calls in app run. its better to use service to handle API calls. App run is usually to use services before the app is loaded. Here's angular calling order: 1. app.config() //only provides can be injected 2.app.run() //services can be injected 3. directive's compile functions (if they are found in the dom) 4. app.controller() 5. directive's link functions (again, if found)

Comment: so what do i need to use if I get a empty json? sorry from all the question i'n new to angular and don't have lots of practice in node

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `$http` request inside of your controller.

```
showFrozen.controller('showFrozenCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/frozen").success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.model = data;
    });
});
```

This is because when you try and print items out in your template (html) what is actually being accessed inside of any `{{ }}` blocks is your `$scope` object. So to make data available to your template you must store it on your `$scope`.

Have a read of [this blog post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/11/angularjs-scopes-an-introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

```
showFrozen.factory('frozenDataSrv',function($http) {
    return {
        getFrozenData: getFrozenData
    };

    function getFrozenData() {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:3000/frozen")
            .then(getFrozenDataComplete)
            .catch(getFrozenDataFailed);

        function getFrozenDataComplete(response) {
            return response.data.results;
        }

        function getFrozenDataFailed(error) {
            logger.error('XHR Failed for getFrozenData.' + error.data);
        }
    }

    });

showFrozen.controller('showFrozenCtrl',function($scope, frozenDataSrv) {
    frozenDataSrv.getFrozenData()
     .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
  })
});
```

Comment: I get undefined and I don't get any response

Comment: what are you getting in getFrozenDataComplete ?

Comment: its looks like you return the response before yo get the data. 
res.json(allFrozen); and you can try this api http://lcboapi.com/products/438457  to see that the problem is not in the service